# Swift Protocol Limitation

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have come across a limitation with swift protocols:

```
protocol P {
}

protocol Q: P {
}

protocol R  {
    var p: P { get set }
}

struct S: R {
    var p: Q
}
```

The code appears to be correct, however it won't build because `S` doesn't conform to protocol `R`, which requires a property of type `P`.

Struct `S` has a property of type `Q` which, by definition, extends `P`.

Is this a bug or by design?

and

Can anyone propose a workaround?